# Cannot connect rows in html with php (logical error display)

Tags: php, html

The html table rows aren't displayed properly. I want to combine the two while loops in the table row but sadly the Update and Delete button are not arranged properly.

here's my code I used two queries that's why it has two while loops

```
     $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT students.stud_id, students.fname, students.lname, students.gender, subjects.sub_code, subjects.subject_name FROM students, enrollments, subjects WHERE students.stud_id = enrollments.stud_id and subjects.sub_code = enrollments.sub_code");

      $sql_sel1=mysql_query("SElECT * FROM enrollments");

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)) //for the first query
        {
            $i++;
            $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
        ?>
            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
                <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sub_code'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>       
            <?php   
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel1)) //for the second query
            {   <!-------The Update and Delete Button are not displayed properly------>
            ?>
                    <td align="center"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>

                    <td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Here is the visual scenario of the problem:

[image]

The desired output must be like this:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ssb4gksph2rvua/htmlerror.PNG?dl=0]

Comment: yes, that is for update and delete button

Comment: What is the num of rowes you get for $sql_sel1?

Comment: the $sql_sel1 is used for update and delete. In that loop it will only delete a specific database because the fields above are from the other table.

Comment: in that while loop its looping twice, thats the reason you get delete and update twice in a row.

Comment: yeah I see, if separate that one the update and delete button will go down. I just want to combine the two while loops in each row.

Comment: what is the structure of enrollment table?

Comment: the enrollment table has two foreign keys the subject_code and student_id.

Comment: where does $row['enroll_num'] from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $sql= "SELECT sts.stud_id, sts.fname, sts.lname, sts.gender, sub.sub_code, sub.subject_name, ets.enroll_num
  FROM students sts
  JOIN enrollements ets ON(sts.stud_id = ets.stud_id)
  JOIN subjects sub ON (sub.sub_code = ets.sub_code)
  GROUP BY sts.stud_id, sub.sub_code";

  $sql_sel=mysql_query($sql);

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)) //for the first query
    {
        $i++;
        $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
    ?>
        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sub_code'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>       
            <td align="center"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>

            <td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I have added enroll_num column in select, And you dont need two queries for this. One query with proper join will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In table header use `colspan='4'` for the last column.

Also be sure that you fill the table with empty columns, where you don't have information to fill with.

**Edit 1:**

Sorry, I haven't seen what's really the problem was. Here should be the working code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel))
    {
        $i++;
        $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
    ?>
        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sub_code'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>   

            <!-- You were already in a while loop -->

                <td align="center"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>

                <td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see you were already in a while loop, and the second one was unnecesary.

**Edit 2:**
  There is a single SQL query now:

```
<?php
// UPDATED SQL QUERY
$sql_sel = mysql_query("SELECT students.stud_id, students.fname, students.lname, students.gender, subjects.sub_code, subjects.subject_name, enrollments.enroll_num 
                        FROM students, enrollments, subjects 
                        WHERE students.stud_id = enrollments.stud_id and subjects.sub_code = enrollments.sub_code");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
    $i++;
    $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sub_code'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>       
        <td align="center"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Why it didn't worked?**
You were reading the whole informations for every student. Then you were reading the whole informations in enrollments table.

You started writing the first row with student information, and inside it you told the server to start writing all the information he had regarding enrollments (without even be linked to that student's id).

When the server reached the second row, all the information available for enrollments were depleted.

Now you have them linked in your first query. Please ask in comments if you need further explanations.

Comment: I want to combine the update and delete button in the second row because they aren't connected

Comment: The second while loop is for the second query in $sql_sel1 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel1)). I want to combine the two while loops in the table row.

Comment: Please add your both queries (with SQL code) and I'll write you a simple working code with comments too.

Comment: The both queries are now added